# Pointers are unsafe but I don't understand ref

Tags: c#, pointers, ref

I want a singleton Problem with a "square" 2x2.
I want to be able to refer to the case by row.
I want to be able to refer to the row by case.
I know I could easily do this in C++ with pointers but it seems like a bad habit to do.
I don't understand how to link my "row" and my "case" together.
The same logic will be there for column but isn't describe in the code
The goal is so changing the value of a Case would affect the value reffered in the Row. How can I achieve this without pointer and with Ref?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Problem.Instance().Show();
        Problem.Instance().Change();
        Problem.Instance().Show();
    }

    public class Problem
    {
        private Case[] cases = null;
        private Row[] rows = null;
        // same logic with private Column[] columns = null;

        static Problem instance = null;
        private Problem()
        {
            cases = new Case[4];
            rows = new Row[2];

            int i = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                cases[i] = new Case();

            for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                rows[i] = new Row(i);

        }
        public static Problem Instance()
        {
            if (instance == null)
                instance = new Problem();
            return instance;
        }
        public Case LinkToRow(int i, ref Row r)
        {
            cases[i].LinkToRow(r);
            return cases[i];
        }
        public void Show()
        {
            rows[0].Show();
        }
        public void Change()
        {
            cases[0].Change();
            cases[1].Change();
        }
    }
    public class Row
    {
        private Case[] ref cases = null;
        public Row(int i)
        {
            ref Row r = this;
            cases = new Case[2];
            cases[0] = Problem.Instance().LinkToRow(0, ref r);
            cases[1] = Problem.Instance().LinkToRow(1, ref r);
        }
        public void Show()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0},{1}", cases[0].Val, cases[1].Val);
        }
    }
    public class Case
    {
        private int val;
        private ref Row r = null;

        public Case()
        {
        }
        public void LinkToRow(Row rr)
        {
            r = rr;
        }
        public int Val { get { return val; } }
        public void Change()
        {
            val++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Arrays are already of reference type. Remember, reference types are already references; "ref" means "make an alias to this variable".  The naming is confusing; a reference to an object and an alias for a variable have almost nothing to do with each other.

Comment: Jon Skeet has a nice [blog post about parameter passing](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html) that you might want to read.

Answer (score 4):

In C#, `private Row r = null;` declares a rebindable reference to an instance of `Row`. `ref` is illegal there and not needed.

In C++, `private: Row r;` would be an instance of `Row`, not a reference. C++ is a different language with very different rules. C# classes can't "be on the stack"; they're always dynamically allocated, and the only way you can manipulate one is via a reference.

In C#, your `private Row r;` is already a reference. A C# reference is kind of like a pointer that you don't have to (and can't) explicitly dereference. Because it's always dereferenced, you can't do pointer arithmetic either. They're subject to many of the same polite fictions ("let's make them pretend it's not a pointer") as C++ references. Just take out `ref`.

A [C# `struct` (e.g. `System.DateTime`)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah19swz4.aspx) is more like a stack instance of a C++ class. This is very different from the C++ struct/class distinction.

The [C# `ref` keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) is a different animal. Nothing to do with references.

In C#, the example below illustrates what [the `ref` keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) is for: Passing references by reference instead of by value. That sounds like I'm pulling your leg but I'm not.

To explain it in terms of C++ semantics, passing a C# reference "by value" is like passing a pointer. You can change the object the caller's pointer points at, but you can't change the caller's pointer itself. You have only the *value* of the caller's pointer.

Passing a C# reference *by reference* is like passing in a pointer to a pointer: You can set `(*p)->Foo = 3;`, and you can also set `*p = new Bar();` (I'm rusty on C/C++, corrections welcomed).

```
public static void F()
{
    String x = "original value";
    FByValue(x);
    Console.WriteLine(x);
    FByReference(ref x);
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}

public static void FByValue(String s)
{
    s = "different value for local copy of parameter only";
}

public static void FByReference(ref String s)
{
    s = "different value for caller's copy, thanks to ref keyword";
}
```

`ref` works only with parameters, never ever with fields; [see MSDN for more detail](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx).

Lastly: `FByValue()` and `FByReference()` would have identical semantics with `int` instead of `String`.

Answer (score 0):

In C# there is a difference between *value types* and *references*.

First, there is nothing wrong with pointers in C/C++, that's how the language works and, that's how the hardware works as well. They can just be confusing to the new user.

In C#, the definition of structures and classes is different than C++:

if you define your data structures as *struct* or as *class*.
A *struct* is an object that gets copied around as it is passed from calls to calls. A *class* on the other hand gets its pointer passed around, similar to a C++ pointer, so if you have references to class instances in C#, you're really referencing the same object, and changes done at one place will be reflected everywhere you hold a reference to that object.